# Plotting the arctanh

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been trying to plot the arctanh function for a while now

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={arctanh(\x) = 0.5*ln(1+\x)/ln(1-\x);}}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-1, xmax=1,
  ymin=-1, ymax=1,
  samples=100,
  enlarge x limits=false,
  grid=both,
  no markers,
  axis equal]
\addplot +[thick] {arctanh(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but it doesn't look right, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not look right because there is a small mistake in the definition of `arctanh`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={arctanh(\x) = 0.5*(ln(1+\x)-ln(1-\x));}}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-1, xmax=1,
  ymin=-1, ymax=1,
  samples=100,
  enlarge x limits=false,
  grid=both,
  no markers,
  axis equal]
\addplot +[thick] {arctanh(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, a somewhat closer representations to yours and a domain that avoids the warnings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={arctanh(\x) = 0.5*(ln((1+\x)/(1-\x)));}}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-1, xmax=1,
  ymin=-1, ymax=1,
  samples=100,
  enlarge x limits=false,
  grid=both,
  no markers,
  axis equal]
\addplot +[thick,domain=-0.99:0.99] {arctanh(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For comparism purpose: run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-math,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-5,-4)(5,4)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-5,-4)(5,4)
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue]{1}{5}{ACOSH(x)}
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red]{-5}{5}{ASINH(x)}
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=green]{-.999}{.999}{ATANH(x)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]